Craft 5 graphql mutation containing a matrix field error
I can't get a mutation to create a Property entry, which includes a matrix field, to work. I've found a few examples for previous craft versions but craft 5 treats matrix fields as entries (I believe) so is fundamentally different.
My latest effort:
mutation SaveCreation($title: String, $featuredImage: [Int], $propertyContent: [propertyContent_MatrixEntryContainerInput]) {
  save_propertyListings_property_Entry(
    featuredImage: $featuredImage
    propertyContent: {entries: $propertyContent, sortOrder: []}
    title: $title
  ) {
    id
    title
    featuredImage {
      id
    }
    propertyContent {
      ... on textBlock_Entry {
        id
        title
        richText
      }
    }
  }
}

Variables:
  "id": 10001,
  "title": "A test entry",
  "featuredImage": 31,
  "propertyContent": { 
    "entries": [{
      "textBlock": {
        "id": "new1",
        "title":"A test block"
      }
    }]
  }
}

The error:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$propertyContent\" got invalid value {\"entries\":[{\"textBlock\":{\"id\":\"new1\",\"title\":\"A test block\"}}]}; Field \"0\" is not defined by type propertyContent_MatrixEntryContainerInput at value.entries.",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 62
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

